# listings does highlight all keywords

Tags: listings

I'm trying to include AMPL syntax highlighting in a report i'm writing.

I've tried using the listings package

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

%Packages

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[squaren,Gray]{SIunits}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\geometry{hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=2cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\definecolor{bdx}{rgb}{0.682, 0.145, 0.451}
\definecolor{bdx}{rgb}{0.674, 0.152, 0.451}

\sectionfont{\centering\color{bdx}}
\subsectionfont{\color{bdx}}
\subsubsectionfont{\centering}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection} - }
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

%Page de titre
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\title{\color{bdx}{\textbf{Test}}
\author{John D}
\date{\today}

% Default fixed font does not support bold face
\DeclareFixedFont{\ttb}{T1}{txtt}{bx}{n}{12} % for bold
\DeclareFixedFont{\ttm}{T1}{txtt}{m}{n}{12}  % for normal

\definecolor{deepblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{deepred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\definecolor{deepgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{deepgrey}{rgb}{0.25,0.25,0.25}



% AMPL style for highlighting

\lstdefinelanguage{ampl}
{
keywords={}
}

\newcommand\amplstyle{\lstset{
language=ampl,
backgroundcolor=\color{white},
basicstyle=\ttm,
emph={subject to, minimize, reset},          % Custom highlighting
otherkeywords={set,param,var,arc,integer,minimize,maximize,subject,to,node,sum,in,Current,complements,integer,solve_result_num,IN,contains,less,suffix,INOUT,default,logical,sum,Infinity,dimen,max,symbolic
,Initial,div,min,table,LOCAL,else,option,then,OUT,environ,setof     ,union,all,exists,shell_exitcodeuntil,binary,forall,solve_exitcodewhile     ,by,if,solve_messagewithin,check,in,solve_result},             % Add keywords here
keywordstyle=\small\ttb\color{deepblue},
emphstyle=\small\ttb\color{deepred},    % Custom highlighting style
morestring=[b]",
stringstyle=\color{deepgreen},
commentstyle=\ttm\color{deepgrey},
frame=tb,                         % Any extra options here
showstringspaces=false            % 
}}


% AMPL environment
\lstnewenvironment{ampl}[1][]
{
\amplstyle
\lstset{#1}
}
{}

% AMPL for external files
\newcommand\amplexternal[2][]{{
\amplstyle
\lstinputlisting[#1]{#2}}}

% AMPL for inline
\newcommand\amplinline[1]{{\amplstyle\lstinline!#1!}}
```

I've tried printing out :

```
\begin{ampl}
set A;
reset;
option solver gurobi;
var j >= 0;
minimize cost;
subject to bob : 
    "But why ?"
\end{ampl}
```

But this does not highlight the words correctly, it seems to go to the first recognition.
For example, "reset" should be emphasized, but is not and the substring "set" is highlighted..

How could I work around this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `otherkeywords` option to add more keywords, but this is wrong. `otherkeywords` should be used to add keywords which include *other* symbols, i.e. characters other than letters or digits that do not usually occur in identifiers.

After using the correct option `morekeywords` you get the correct result:

```
\newcommand\amplstyle{\lstset{
    ...
    emph={subject to, minimize, reset},          % Custom highlighting
    morekeywords={set,param,var, ...},           % Add keywords here
    ...
}}
```

> [image]

Comment: Brilliant, thanks ! This is exactly the explanation I needed ;)